WordPress: Website moved to new server, admin user no longer has rights
I moved a WordPress website to a new server. I created a 1:1 copy of the entire website and uploaded it via SSH.
I imported the database with a different prefix and changed the url via wp cli seach-replace.
I can still see the old page on the new installation.
However, the installation screen is displayed via /wp-admin.
I specified the installation process and the new prefix.
After that, I was logged in, but my admin no longer has any permissions.
When I enter /wp-admin, I also get the message that my user has no rights.
I tried the whole thing again locally, but everything is fine here! My admin is an admin user!
Could this be due to the hosting? Have I overlooked something?

Did you check your wp-config.php?

This question is solved! It was a problem with the hosting, not wordpress.
